# Fail an actor if a Future call fails

Tags: scala, akka

I am executing something in a future call. I will return the result to the sender on successful completion or fail the actor if the future call fails. Which will be handled by the parent where a RoundRobinPool with a supervisor strategy is implemented.

Here is the code snippet.

```
private def getData(sender: ActorRef): Unit = {

    dao.getData().mapTo[List[Data]].map(result => sender ! result)
      .onFailure {
        case e: NullPointerExcetpion => {
          println("+++++++ Throwing exception")
      // throwning the exception from here doesn't cause the supervisor to restart this actor
          throw t
        }
      }

      // throwing the exception from here makes the supervisor strategy to take action
      throw new NullPointerExcetpion

  }
```

How can we make the actor fail if the future returns an exception ?

Cheers,

Utsav

Comment: What do you mean by "failing the Actor" ?

Comment: Propagating it back to the user and killing the actor. The behavior that would cause the supervisor to restart the actor. As SupervisorStrategy.Restart is used in the supervisor in case of null pointer exceptions.

Comment: More importantly why is it working when I explicitly throwing the error from outside the Future functions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `onFailure` callback is thrown from an arbitrary thread, and not the one the actor is running on. What you can do is pipe the result to yourself, and then throw:

```
case class MyFailure(e: Throwable)

def receive: {
  case MyFailure(e) => throw e
}

private def getData(sender: ActorRef): Unit = {
  dao
   .getData()
   .mapTo[List[Data]]
   .recover {
     case e => MyFailure(e)
   }
   .pipeTo(self)
}
```

Or as @jrudolph suggested:

```
def receive: {
  case Status.Failure(e) => throw e
}

private def getData(sender: ActorRef): Unit = {
  dao
   .getData()
   .mapTo[List[Data]]
   .pipeTo(self)
}
```

Comment: Or even without `recover` by receiving the `Status.Failure(ex)` message which is provided by `pipeTo`.

Comment: I will still be able to retain the map on my actual future call, right ?

Comment: @user520209 Definitely, you'll just need to add a case to your receive method which accepts the type of the result which is returned if an exception isn't thrown.

Comment: I meant whether I can still directly send the result to the sender in the map pf in case the future call is successful , like in the question, without having to pipe the result to self.

Comment: @user520209 You can add a map which passes on the message to the sender, but then would still get the result sent to yourself anyway. It would be cleaner to pipe it to yourself and then pass it to the sender. If you want you can use `become` instead of adding it to the current receive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135232/discussion-between-user520209-and-yuval-itzchakov).